# Retrieve indices of specific date

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to retrieve the indices corresponding to a specific month for my data set.

This is for keeping track of the index lines for training a Neural Network after the train-test data split. I want to know for which dates my predictions correspond to.

I have tried the following in which i retrieve the indices corresponding to a specific day. Is there a way to have an argument like * in the day so i retrieve 1 whole month

```
target_date = pd.to_datetime('2013-10-24').date()
metadata.loc[metadata.Starttime.dt.date == target_date, :].index.values
```

which gives

```
array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I would expect something like:

```
array([10, 14, 17], dtype=int64)
```

Where 10,14,17 are the indices corresponding to the month i searched for, not a specific day

Example:

```
installation = range(0,5)
equipment = range(0,5)
tag_name = range(0,5)
start_time = ['2013-10-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-9-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-8-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-7-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-6-15 02:30:24.670']

dic =  {'Installation':installation,'Equipment':equipment,'Tag name':tag_name,'Starttime':start_time,}  

metadata = pd.DataFrame(dic)  #Create the dataframe
metadata['Starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(metadata['Starttime'])

target_date = pd.to_datetime('2013-10-15').date()
metadata.loc[metadata.Starttime.dt.date == target_date, :].index.values
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Done. I added it in the end :)

Comment: Thank you, so now what is expected output? I check `print (metadata)` and need rturn only first row? Because another are different months...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your filtering condition to get the whole month:

```py
metadata.loc[
    (metadata.Starttime.dt.month == 10) & 
    (metadata.Starttime.dt.year == 2013)
].index.values
```

Comment: Yeah as i figured it was pretty simple. I need to check pandas more. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you need compare month peiod created by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for column and for scalar [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html):

```
installation = range(0,5)
equipment = range(0,5)
tag_name = range(0,5)
#change first 3 datetimes for same months
start_time = ['2013-10-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-10-16 02:30:24.670', '2013-10-17 02:30:24.670',
              '2013-7-15 02:30:24.670', '2013-6-15 02:30:24.670']

dic =  {'Installation':installation,'Equipment':equipment,
        'Tag name':tag_name,'Starttime':start_time}  

metadata = pd.DataFrame(dic)  #Create the dataframe
metadata['Starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(metadata['Starttime'])
print (metadata)
   Installation  Equipment  Tag name               Starttime
0             0          0         0 2013-10-15 02:30:24.670
1             1          1         1 2013-10-16 02:30:24.670
2             2          2         2 2013-10-17 02:30:24.670
3             3          3         3 2013-07-15 02:30:24.670
4             4          4         4 2013-06-15 02:30:24.670

target_date = pd.to_datetime('2013-10-15').to_period('m')
idx = metadata.loc[metadata.Starttime.dt.to_period('m') == target_date].index.values
print (idx)
[0 1 2]
```